# How can I be sure that a photo from unsplash.com wasn't stolen from another person?

Tags: commercial-photography

As you all probably know, most photos on unsplash.com can be used for commercial purposes. My question now is, how can I be sure, that the photo from unsplash.com that I would be using (e.g. on my website) isn't actually a picture that was stolen from another person. How can I be sure that the person that the picture got stolen from, is not going to sue me?

Comment: Do a reverse image search and see if you find it elsewhere?

Comment: Maybe I'm naive, but do you think the first response of a copyright holder would be to bounce you into a courtroom? Surely the first thing they would do is simply request you take down the copyrighted material. You could even put a message on your site (not that it would help much, but at least it shows good faith) - details on where images are sourced, and how to get in contact with you if there are any rights issues.

Comment: @osullic [There are/have been people who have deliberately enticed others to make minor technical breaches of licenses and then shaken them down for money](https://pluralistic.net/2023/04/01/pixsynnussija/#pilkunnussija), so it all depends who you're dealing with.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Also depends in which country you are, fortunately.

Answer (score 3):

> how can I be sure, that the photo from unsplash.com that I would be using (e.g. on my website) isn't actually a picture that was stolen from another person. How can I be sure that the person that the picture got stolen from, is not going to sue me?

Pithy answer, but nonetheless true: you can't be sure, at all. You roll the dice and you take your chances.

There are several cases of content creators (YouTubers, website designers, etc.) going out of their way to find and pay for original photos, stock footage, theme songs, etc., and wind up later getting sued because the person they paid for supposedly original content used copyrighted material, and were forced to take down their entire body of work.

You simply can't be sure. You can try to do your due diligence, and even pay for the effort, and still not know.

In my opinion (completely not based on legal experience at all), your risks are higher of using "free content" from places like unsplash.com **precisely because** you aren't paying for the free content. Without the profit incentive that image/content brokers like Getty Images have, the ability of Unsplash.com to ensure and enforce rights-free provenance is diminished.

In short, pay up for more peace of mind, or go free/cheap, and expose yourself to higher risk. It's a common business choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can not be certain that the photos were uploaded in accordance with copyright laws. But generally the individual who uploaded the image attests that they are doing it with full rights to do so (i.e. it is their original work). And that would/should hold you harmless in terms of penalty; but that doesn't mean you would be allowed to continue use either.

> **8. Prohibited Conduct**
>
> BY USING THE SERVICE YOU AGREE NOT TO:
>
> A. Use the Service for any illegal purpose or in violation of any laws or regulations;
>
> B. Violate or encourage others to violate third party rights, including the infringement or misappropriation of intellectual property rights;
>
> C. Upload, post, or publish any User Content that is unlawful, defamatory, libelous, objectionable, profane, indecent, pornographic, harassing, threatening, hateful, or otherwise inappropriate;

However, you can be certain that some images cannot be used for commercial purposes. Images from sources like Unsplash do not confer any licensing; so images of recognizable faces, trademarks, and other original art may not be usable for certain purposes.

This is made clear in [Unsplash's Terms of Service](https://unsplash.com/terms)...

> This means that Photos on the Service come with a very, very broad copyright license under the Unsplash License. This is why we say that they are “Free to Use.” Note that the Unsplash License does not include the right to use:
>
> A. Trademarks, logos, or brands that appear in Photos
>
> B. People’s images if they are recognizable in the Photos
>
> C. Works of art or authorship that appear in Photos
>
> If you download photos with any of these depicted in them, you may need the permission of the brand owner of the brand or work of authorship or individual depending on how you use the Photo. Please see our FAQs for more information and, if you still aren’t sure, you should probably talk to a lawyer who knows about these things.

Such images from paid sources (e.g. Getty) will include required licensing, or they will be indicated as being for editorial use only.